# OpenCV - Type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv

Okay this is super weird.. I'm 10/10 sure my code is correct ?

```
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(gameWindow[0], gameWindow[1], gameWindow[0], gameWindow[1]))
img_np = np.array(img)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imshow("f", frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Yet it throws me this error saying:

```
frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported
```

Wow i'm seriously confused.

Comment: Maybe `img_np = np.array(img, np.uint8)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Welp now a new error showed up `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Image'`

Comment: I’m not so sure about ImageGrab, but bbox doesn’t look very good to me.  It might not be the cause for your error anyway.

Comment: @QuangHoang How else would u take a screenshot and display using cv2?

Comment: You’re passing the same top left corner and bottom right corner to bbox. That would return an empty image?

Comment: Try change `img_np = np.array(img)` to `img_np = np.array(img).astype(np.uint8)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `img_np = np.array(img.getdata(), dtype = 'uint8')`? Because numpy cannot convert an `Image` to a `np.array` easily. [`getdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) returns a sequence-like object, so that you can convert it to a numpy array.